# Indian roof turtles have fungal infections

Tags: turtles

I bought a pair of indian roof turtles 3 days ago. They have some problems like bacterial/fungal infection on their legs and white dots on their shells.

I have given them salt bath and cleaned their shell with brush.  They are spending 2 hrs on uv light and there is some improvement too.

If there anything else I can do?

[image: fungal infectjon]

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question a little - It might help to state the issue you're trying to fix a little more obviously - are you asking for advice on the infection and white dots? Have you consulted a vet?  Also I believe you can simply upload images under 2mb by selecting the image upload option in the editor - if its a larger image you need to resize it.

Comment: Not possible to consult vet here. How can I upload photo. I am trying to upload a photo

Comment: Done. The fungal/bacterial infection at legs is looking good now. Skin is coming back so it may be bacterial. Can u tell something about shell? Someone told me to apply betadine

Comment: I don't know anything about turtles - but other folks here would know.

Comment: Do u belong to India ?